# (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)] org.apache.catalina.loader.Weba.................: this web application instance has been stopped already

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, activemq-artemis

I have a spring-boot application which connected to ActiveMQ Artemis. When deployed in Tomcat it is working fine, but when deploying another version of same application and after stoping old one I get this error in the log continuously:

```
(ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading
Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [io.netty.util.collection.IntObjectHashMap].
The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access. 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [io.netty.util.collection.IntObjectHashMap]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1311)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1299)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1158)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.loadClass(LoaderUtil.java:163)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.loadClass(ThrowableProxy.java:582)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.toExtendedStackTrace(ThrowableProxy.java:698)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.getThrownProxy(Log4jLogEvent.java:566)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.format(ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowablePatternConverter.format(ExtendedWhitespaceThrowablePatternConverter.java:53)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:38)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$PatternSerializer.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:334)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toText(PatternLayout.java:233)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:58)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:177)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:170)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:433)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:403)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2163)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2118)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2101)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1995)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1967)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.warn(Log4jLogger.java:259)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.Slf4JLogger.warn(Slf4JLogger.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.handleLoopException(EpollEventLoop.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:328)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2020-04-02 11:37:33.587  WARN 10941 --- [-netty-threads)] i.n.c.e.EpollEventLoop: Unexpected exception in the selector loop.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/collection/IntObjectHashMap$2
    at io.netty.util.collection.IntObjectHashMap.values(IntObjectHashMap.java:221) ~[netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.closeAll(EpollEventLoop.java:355) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.22.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:322) [netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.22.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) [netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

**After restarting Tomcat the issue solved, but I need to solve this without restarting Tomcat, because I don't want to restart production Tomcat.**

My artemis configuration in spring-boot app:

```java
@Bean("connectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(JmsProperties appProperties) {
   ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(appProperties.getArtemis().getBrokerUrl());
   cf.setUser(appProperties.getArtemis().getUser());
   cf.setPassword(appProperties.getArtemis().getPassword());
   return cf;
}
```

I create ActiveMQ connection factory here because spring-boot allows only userName and password in `application.yml` for artemis, but I need to set `consumerWindowSize` in broker url like this: `tcp://localhost:61616?consumerWindowSize=0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection factory ActiveMQConnection uses netty to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis if the url has a `tcp` schema. When the application is stopped by tomcat, the `shutdownGracefully` is called on the netty group to stop all netty threads.

However, `shutdownGracefully` method is asynchronous so tomcat complete the stop procedure before all netty threads are stopped. If a netty thread tries to load a class after the relative application is stopped, the tomcat class loader throws an `IllegalStateException` causing the errors in the log.

A `CachingConnectionFactory` with a pause should mitigate this issue:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(JmsProperties appProperties) {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(appProperties.getArtemis().getBrokerUrl());
    cf.setUser(appProperties.getArtemis().getUser());
    cf.setPassword(appProperties.getArtemis().getPassword());

    return new CachingConnectionFactory(cf) {
        @Override
        public void destroy() {
            super.destroy();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("CachingConnectionFactory is destroyed!");
        }
    };
}
```